# XCode 6.2 default View Controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I've created a new Cocoa app in `XCode 6.2`. It has only the `AppDelegate.m/.h` files, `Info.plist` and `MainMenu.xib`. What is the default NSViewController?

I need to be able to grab the view controller's instance from code, but I can't find the instance...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default NSViewController in that case. The defaults provide you with a blank window only. You will have to create one yourself. Here is one example of how people do it.

[one example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xftvGgbnYEc&spfreload=10)